# 433MHz RF communication between Arduino + Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-3, pi-4, pi-3b+, arduino, communication

I bought a 433MHz receiver and transmitter to send data from a Raspberry Pi 3 to an Arduino Uno.

I searched the internet for tutorials, Arduino StackExchange and Raspberry Pi StackExchange but I did not find anything helpful.

Comment: please do not crosspost ... https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/84418/433mhz-rf-communication-between-arduino-raspberry-pi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [433Utils Library](https://github.com/ninjablocks/433Utils) is probably what you're looking for.
The author even provides [example arduino sketches](https://github.com/ninjablocks/433Utils/tree/master/Arduino_sketches). If you want the Arduino to listen the [RF-Sniffer](https://github.com/ninjablocks/433Utils/tree/master/Arduino_sketches/RF_Sniffer) is what you need!

---

There are also more great tutorials online [just like this one](https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/let-raspberry-pis-communicate-with-each-other-per-433mhz-wireless-signals/).

Comment: I think that's what I need. I am already testing code from the GitHub repo.

Answer (score 0):

You could try my implementation of VirtualWire to send small data packets between a Pi and an Arduino.

http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_vw

> Class to send and receive radio messages compatible with the Virtual
> Wire library for Arduinos. This library is commonly used with 313MHz
> and 434MHz radio tranceivers.